# Actualizar activity con cambios en adapter Xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin

Buenas.

Me gustaría saber si sería posible actualizar el activity padre que contiene un adapter cuando en éste se produzca un evento.

Explico con un poco más de detalle: 
Tengo un activity que carga un adapter con una serie de información contenida en cada item y un botón para un cambio de estado (por cada uno de los items).

Necesitaría que cada vez que el usuario hace click en el botón de cambio de estado de los items actualizara el activity padre.

Os adjunto el código de mi adapter (he omitido algunas partes para dejar lo relevante)

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

```
  class adapter_listview_pedidos_asignados_int : 
    BaseAdapter<DetalleRutaAsignadaIntClass>    {

        ImageView btnEntregaRealizadaOK1;

        ImageView btnEntregaRealizadaConInci1;


        List<DetalleRutaAsignadaIntClass> items;
        Activity context;

        string _ok = "OK";

        View _view;


        public override int Count   {
            get { return items.Count; }
        }

        public override DetalleRutaAsignadaIntClass this[int position] {
            get { return items[position]; }
        }

        public adapter_listview_pedidos_asignados_int(Activity context, List<DetalleRutaAsignadaIntClass> items) : base() {
            this.context = context;
            this.items = items;
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)    {
            return position;
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  {
            View view = null;
            DetalleRutaAsignadaIntClass item = items[position];
            if (convertView == null) {
                view = new View(context);
            }
            else {
                view = convertView;
            }

            if (view != null)       {
                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.item_pedido_asign_ruta_int, null);
                _view = view;

                view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblNombreLinea).Text = item.nombre_linea.ToString();
                view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblDistancia).Text = item.distancia_aproximada.ToString();

                view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblNombreLocalizacionOrigen).Text = item.nombre_localizacion_origen.ToString();
                view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblNombreLocalizacionDestino).Text = item.nombre_localizacion_destino.ToString();


                view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.btnEntregaRealizadaOK1).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;

                btnEntregaRealizadaOK1 = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.btnEntregaRealizadaOK1);
                btnEntregaRealizadaOK1.Click += delegate    {
            bool res = actualiza_estado(string id_pedido, string resultado);
                //*** Aquí es donde quiero actualizar el activity padre ***//       
                };

            }
            return view;
        }

        private bool actualiza_estado(string id_pedido, string resultado) {
            bool devolver = false;

            librerias.helpers.WebService consulta = new librerias.helpers.WebService(helper.helper.url_web_service, "cambia_estado_pedido_a_finalizado_int");
            try {
                consulta.AddParameter("id_pedido", id_pedido.ToString());
                consulta.AddParameter("resultado", resultado.ToString());

                consulta.Invoke();
            }
            finally { consulta.PosInvoke(); }

            devolver = Convert.ToBoolean(consulta.ResultString);
            consulta = null;

            return devolver;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Si eso soluciona tu pregunta, te sugiero que lo coloques como respuesta y la marques como aceptada, para una mayor organización para que los usuarios que la puedan necesitar la encuentren con más facilidad. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabo de dar con la solución y mira que llevaba un buen rato con esto. Relativamente sencillo pero lo dejo aquí para cualquier otra persona: justo después de la llamada a actualiza_estado he hecho lo siguiente:

```
Intent act_actualizado= new Intent(context.Intent);
act_actualizado.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask); 
this.context.Finish(); 
Application.Context.StartActivity(act_actualizado);
```

Cualquier mejora o sugerencia es, por supuesto, apreciada.

Answer (score 1):

yo lo resolví asi funciona pero nose si sea lo correcto

```
ListView listaTra;
    List<mantenimientoProsesado> listaTraItems;
    bool actualizacionesBandera = false;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ListaTrabajosPersonal);
        listaTra = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ListaListaTrabajosPersonal);
        listasActualizar();
        listaTra.ItemClick += listaTra_ItemClick;
    }

    protected override void OnPostResume()
    {
        base.OnPostResume();
        if (actualizacionesBandera)
        {
            listasActualizar();
            actualizacionesBandera = false;
        }
    }

    public void listasActualizar()
    {
        listaTraItems = ;//cargas tu lista 
        listaTra.Adapter = new ListaTrabajosPersonalAdaptador(this, listaTraItems);
    }

    void listaTra_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        actualizacionesBandera = true;

        Toast.MakeText(this, listaTraItems[e.Position].ClienteAgencia, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        Intent Navegar = new Intent(this, typeof(Mantenimiento));
        StartActivity(Navegar);

    }
```